# Why the dialog don't display?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to learn how to develop a plugin in intellij idea , so I create a new plugin project and write a easy dialog to test .

```
public class TranslateAction extends AnAction {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    // TODO: insert action logic here
    Messages.showMessageDialog("Hello World !", "Information", Messages.getInformationIcon());
}}
```

Below is my plugin.xml:

```
  <actions>
<!-- Add your actions here -->

<action id="TestTranslation.TestTranslation" class="action.TranslateAction" text="Translate"
        description="translate words">
  <add-to-group group-id="EditMenu" anchor="first"/>
  <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="meta T"/>
</action>
```

Now when I click "run" , it will open a new window to let me create a new project . And I see my item in Edit menu , but when I click it , nothing happened .

[image]

Comment: This should work. Please make sure you've rebuilt your project correctly after adding the implementation of actionPerformed().

Comment: @yole That is weird , it works when I use my keymap control + T which I defined .